How to prove the Cauchy Criterion for Product?
I am trying to figure out how to prove the Cauchy Criterion for products apply for all $\epsilon$.
Specifically {$u_n$}^$\infty$_${n=1}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that for all $\epsilon > 0$, There exists a natural number N such that if $m \geqslant n \geqslant N$ implies $\lvert \prod_{k=n}^m u_k - 1\rvert < $ $\epsilon$ $\prod_{u_k}$ is convergent.
My idea was to turn this into a sum with natural logarithims and then try to prove it is a cauchy sequence, but my attempts at it don't seem to look right because I have to fight with absolute values, on top of other examples i've seen of proving cauchy sequences looking much more complex. Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Your idea is fine. You could let $v_k = \ln u_k$, and the condition would involve$$\left|e^{\sum_{k=n}^m v_k} - 1\right| < \varepsilon.$$From here, you could appeal to the continuity of $x \mapsto e^x$, to reduce this to the Cauchy criterion for sums.
